# Why does this while stop after first iteration?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

If I do the following

```
tr -cd 'a-z' < /dev/urandom | fold -w10 | head -n40 > pw
for f in $(seq -w 40); do echo linux$f.example.com;done > hosts

while read -r x && read -r y <&3; do ssh $x -l root echo $y;done <hosts 3<pw
```

then the loop stops after the first iteration, but if I insert an `echo` (which is not what I want) then it loops through all 40.

```
while read -r x && read -r y <&3; do echo ssh $x -l root echo $y;done <hosts 3<pw
```

**Question**

How can I make it execute all 40 iterations, without making a temp file first?

Comment: Maybe tell us what it is supposed to do since it doesn't work!

Comment: I wonder if `ssh` is stealing your fds and reading/flushing them. Try closing stdin and `&3` for the `ssh` command?

Comment: @EtanReisner Adding `</dev/null 2>/dev/null` solved the problem. Thanks =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like `ssh` is seeing and draining your fds.

Close the fds to `ssh` when you run it.

Answer (score 1):

How about this for avoiding temporary files...

```
#!/bin/bash
h=1
LC_CTYPE="C" tr -cd 'a-z' < /dev/urandom | fold -w10 | head -n40 | \
   while read x; do
      host=$(printf "linux%02d.example.com" $h)
      echo $x $host
      ((h++))
   done
```

Another way of avoiding the temporary files is to use process substitution to generate the two inputs you require and then paste them pairwise onto separate lines before reading both in a single loop like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
paste \
   <(LC_CTYPE="C" tr -cd 'a-z' < /dev/urandom | fold -w10)        \
   <(for f in $(seq -w 40); do echo linux$f.example.com;done) |   \
   head -n40 | while read x y; do
      echo $x $y
   done
```

Or you can do it the other way around if you are concerned about variables inside subshells:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read x y; do
   echo $x $y
done < <( paste \
           <(LC_CTYPE="C" tr -cd 'a-z' < /dev/urandom | fold -w10)        \
           <(for f in $(seq -w 40); do echo linux$f.example.com;done) |   \
           head -n40)
```

Comment: The sub-shells implied by using pipes make that `h` counter not work correctly.

Comment: @EtanReisner Ok, thank you. I will check in the morning - though I did run it on my Mac and it seemed correct.

Comment: @EtanReisner It seems to run fine on my machine. There is only one subshell involved, and that processes the `while` loop. It inherits `h` from its parent as it starts and then merrily increments it each time through the loop. I can't see any problem - could you explain what you mean please?

Comment: Ah, my apologies, I missed that `h` was for use by the sub-shell only in this case and not being carried across various sub-shells. (Though there are actually three or four sub-shells involved in that pipeline I believe, one for each section of the pipeline though potentially not for at least one segment it is uses the current shell.)